# Programs to circuit conversion

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

Suppose we have an algorithm for a decision problem with $n$ bit inputs that runs in $DTIME[f(n)]$ is there ways to convert to circuits of $O(f(n))$ size with AND, OR and NOT gates?

How about when we go from circuits to programs?

Answer (score 2):

The [Cook–Levin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem) shows how to construct a circuit of size $f(n)^{O(1)}$. I'm not sure what's the best exponent.

The opposite direction is impossible, since circuits of size 1 can compute the following language:
$$ \{ w : \text{the $|w|$th Turing machine halts on the empty input} \}. $$
More generally, circuits of size 1 can compute any language in which the answer depends only on the length of the input.

Comment: 'circuits of size 1 can compute the following language:....' why?

Comment: That's a nice question for you.

Comment: Dont get it that looks undecidable.

Comment: @Brout It's a map from length to a non-computable predicate. That's the most standard example for non-uniformity allowing for strictly more than r.e. languages.

Comment: @dkaee Is there reference for this (it is new to me)?

Comment: It’s a very simple fact. The proof is almost immediate. I suspect we don’t have the same notion of circuits computing a language, which is why you find it hard to fathom.